# How to do something in C when a process terminates without hanging the program?

Tags: c, shell, unix

Currently, I'm learning about processes on the UNIX system.

My issue is, I need to do something every time a background process terminates. That means that I can't use the typical functionality of waitpid because then the process won't be running in the background and it'll hang the program.

I'm also aware of the SIGCHLD signal which is sent whenever a child of the parent process is terminated however I'm not aware of how to get the process id of the said process which I will need.

What is the proper way to go about this in C? I've tried things such as WNOHANG option on waitpid however that of course only gets called once so I don't see how I could make that apply to my current situation.

Comment: I believe you can issue a `wait` call inside a signal handler. Although not necessary, you could do `waitpid` with `WNOHANG` there. See `man signal-safety` for a list of calls you can do safely from within a handler. If you need to do non-safe calls, it depends on how your base level loop is designed [or waiting] for the handler to send back any necessary data to the base level.

Comment: Yup! This was the solution. For reference, at least in my case, using sigaction is overkill because all I needed to do was check if a process being terminated was in a list. Just simply using wait() in the sigchld handler function worked! 

My confusion was in not understand how similar the wait() and waitpid() functions are, for some reason it had elluded me wait() itself did not return the pid of the process that has terminated. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

> waitpid because then the process won't be running in the background and it'll hang the program.

If the process won't be running in the backrgound, `waitpid` *with the pid argument* will exit immediately (assuming there are no pid clashes). And still, that's not true - just use `WNOHANG`...

> however I'm not aware of how to get the process id of the said process which I will need. What is the proper way to go about this in C?

Use `sigaction` to register the signal handler and use the field `si_pid` from the second signal handler argument of type `siginfo_t`. From [man sigaction](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sigaction.2.html):

> SIGCHLD fills in si_pid, si_uid, si_status, si_utime, and si_stime,
> providing information about the child.  The si_pid field is the
> process ID of the child

A working example that uses it is in the [man 3p wait](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/wait.3p.html) page under section `Waiting for a Child Process in a Signal Handler for SIGCHLD`.

> What is the proper way to go about this in C?

The C standard is not aware of child processes and SIGCHLD signals. These are part of your operating system. In this case the behavior is standardized by [POSIX](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/signal.h.html).